# SQL query runs fast on local computers but slow on production server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I am running a fairly basic query on my local development machine which runs almost instantly. However on the server its taking around 3-4 seconds to return results. I have ran Client Statistics on both machines and get these results.

Local machine:

```
Query Profile Statistics            
  Number of INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE statements    0       
  Rows affected by INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE statements 0       
  Number of SELECT statements   3       
  Rows returned by SELECT statements    17      
  Number of transactions    0       
Network Statistics          
  Number of server roundtrips   2       
  TDS packets sent from client  2       
  TDS packets received from server  9       
  Bytes sent from client    342     
  Bytes received from server    30141       
Time Statistics         
  Client processing time    16      
  Total execution time  508     
  Wait time on server replies   492
```

Server machine:

```
Query Profile Statistics            
  Number of INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE statements    0       
  Rows affected by INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE statements 0       
  Number of SELECT statements   3   
  Rows returned by SELECT statements    17      
  Number of transactions    0       
Network Statistics          
  Number of server roundtrips   2       
  TDS packets sent from client  2       
  TDS packets received from server  9       
  Bytes sent from client    342     
  Bytes received from server    31560       
Time Statistics         
  Client processing time    16      
  Total execution time  3638        
  Wait time on server replies   3622
```

What could be the reason for it taking so much longer on the server? Its causing webpages to load slowly and hence users and search engines are penalising me.

Comment: Can you post the actual slow and fast query plan xml (use pastebin and link it here) ? Also, what is the max memory on the server and the local machine ? Check `sys.configuration` to see if there is any anomaly between local and remote server.

Comment: Are index statistics updated on production database? Is something else running on hardware it's using?

Comment: @MarcinS. I ran sp_updatestats on the server and updated the statistics on all tables - but no difference. It still takes 3 seconds to run on the server. My local computers are Intel Core i7 machines. The server is an AMD Quad-Core CPU. Would the CPU difference really cause such a delay in performance on a simple select query?

Comment: @volumeone What's the load on server? Are there any other processes running (try using [sp_WhoIsActive](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/tags/who+is+active/default.aspx) from Adam Machanic or at least check what is Activity Monitor telling You)?
That shouldn't be the case (it's not nearly as important as statistics, performance wise), but maybe Your db is fragmented (like >70% fragmentation on indexes)?  If so, check with [Ola Hallegren's](https://ola.hallengren.com/) Index and Statistics Maintenance

Comment: @volumeone Try using Ola's script instead of sp_updatestats, it has it's [issues](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/07/sql-statistics/statistics-updates).

Comment: @volumeone, have you tried running the query from SSMS locally on the database server?  I'm curious if the wait time is network related.

Comment: @DanGuzman I can only remote desktop into the server. I ran it direct from SSMS on the server and its the same execution time.

Comment: @MarcinS. Thank you for the Ola scripts link. I have ran the Update Statistics procedure and it hasn't made any difference.

Comment: @volumeone what about answers to the other questions?

Comment: @volumeone, do you mean running the query via SSMS RDPed into the database server is the same speed as with SSMS on your local dev box?  Given the execution plans have the same shape, I'm wondering if the cause is latency is due to something in the client/server network stack (including HIPS) rather performance of the query itself.  Is the problem just this query or overall SQL performance?

Comment: @DanGuzman All queries take longer on the server in general. I tried a different query and it takes 243ms on local but 421ms on the server. However its still quick enough for my needs. But this one query is not taking just double the time, its taking quite a lot longer! Yes I RDped onto the server, launched SSMS and ran the SP. It stil takes 3 seconds to return results which is should be around 500ms.

Comment: @MarcinS. I ran sp_WhoIsActive and I get no records back which means nobody is using it. The server under very very light load with only a handful of users maxiumum at peak. I have rebuilt all the indexes so didn't think fragmentation was a problem?

Comment: Dont you think the server is being accessed for a lot of users, and the client machine not?

Comment: @volumeone Didn't think rebuilding would help if updating stats didn't help either.   
Just noticed hardware differences - it shouldn't matter  THAT much, at least if both machines aren't really outdated. What disks are beneath both machines?
    Maybe something in configuration is different? MaxDOP, Cost Threshold for Parallelism, memory configuration? Just check them if possible.
Or maybe some trace flags (check `DBCC TRACESTATUS(-1); ` on both machines if possible.